# How to verify that a function is bounded in its domain

Tags: real-analysis, optimization

I have a problem with an exercise. I have to study the stationary point of this function:
$$f(x,y) = (y-1)^2(y^2-x^2)$$
Well, this is not so hard, just calculate the gradient and the points that make it 0, Hessian matrix etc. Next the exercise ask to prove that the function is **bounded** in its domain ($\mathbb{R}^2$), that is $\exists\,m, M\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $$m\le f(x,y)\le M\quad\quad\forall(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2$$How would you prove it? I tried to do some manipulation on the function to prove that it's bounded by two constant but I can't reached the solution.

Comment: @zick094 That function is not bounded. For example $f(x,0)=-x^2$ which diverges to $-\infty$.

Comment: ok, that's true. So it's sufficient to find a direction in which the function diverges?

Comment: you can also set $$y=tx$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a polynomial function. Nonconstant polynomials are not bounded.

For fixed $y\neq 1$, this function is of the form $a+bx^2$, which can be made as large in magnitude as desired by taking $x$ sufficiently large.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If this doesn't happen, how can I prove more generally? Taking points like $(x,mx)$?

Comment: For polynomials, it will ALWAYS happen. Fix all but one of the variables, and it becomes a polynomial in one variable. Then it behaves asymptotically like the leading term. (You may have to be careful not to choose values of the other variables which make it a constant polynomial, as $y=1$ does here.) For nonpolynomial functions, your suggestion is often a good first try.